# Remove c__DisplayClass from code coverage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I'm getting c__DisplayClass files appearing in my code coverage analysis that appear to be auto generated code from closures (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025618/extra-classes-in-code-coverage-results-window)).

My question is, HOW do you remove this auto generated code from code coverage results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research, I've discovered you can make use of a .runsettings file ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530(v=vs.120).aspx)).

You can customize your code coverage results within this file like so:

```
<CodeCoverage>
  <ModulePaths>
    <Exclude></Exclude>
  </ModulePaths>
  <Functions>
    <Exclude>
      <Function>.*c__DisplayClass.*</Function>
    </Exclude>
  </Functions>
</CodeCoverage>
```

This gave me the results I wanted.  All auto generated c__DisplayClass functions are excluded from the results.

Comment: Is there any way that this can be done when running code coverage via Command Prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Anthony's excellent answer, I had lots of auto generated rubbish which can be hidden neatly with the following .runsettings file:

```
<CodeCoverage>
    <ModulePaths>
        <Exclude></Exclude>
    </ModulePaths>
    <Functions>
        <Exclude>
            <Function>.*&lt;*&gt;.*</Function>
        </Exclude>
    </Functions>
</CodeCoverage>
```

Note that `&lt;` and `&gt;` are the triangular brackets `<` and `>` so this should (in my experience) cover all automatically generated code in the coverage results.